# AWS lambda auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud

I'm trying to develop a data pipeline using AWS lambda and I needed to know if it auto-scales immediately or does it require a warm-up time?

Comment: You'll probably find this series of articles very interesting: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)

Comment: You may be confusing two different "pre-warm" concepts, one traditionally related to ELB (scaling) and the other to Lambda functions (cold start). The 'scaling' concern relates to the service being able to spin up more compute in parallel quickly as opposed to the startup latency of an individual Lambda function (its "cold start" time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda has this concept of `Provisioned concurrency`. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html):

> Provisioned concurrency initializes a requested number of execution environments so that they are prepared to respond immediately to your function's invocations. Note that configuring provisioned concurrency incurs charges to your AWS account.

You can set a value for how many execution environments be prepared for parallel invocations. This will guarantee that your lambda wont require a warm-up time as long as you stay inside that value and you wont have more parallel executions.

Otherwise, it wont be guaranteed that your function will be warmed-up. If you have nothing set for provisioned concurrency, you most likely will have cold-starts.